# Trajectory of Instantaneous center of rotation of a disc performing both rotational and translational motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

I am posting the specific problem I am dealing with for reference and then explain the part I am confused with.

[image]

**My Understanding and approach to the problem**

I identified that in the ground frame the disc will have some inertia and thus simply remain stationary as the plank below slides away.When viewing from the plank's reference frame it's acceleration will be added to the COM of the disc in the opposite direction.So initially the instantaneous center of rotation is at the exact center.

**The Confusion**

I am unable to visualise how the instantaneous center of rotation will change as the COM gains velocity due to the acceleration. The solution that I found said that the points that have tangential velocity along the acceleration will have some added velocity while those against will have
some net velocity in the direction of the acceleration.According to me if that happened then the rotation would completely stop which does not make any intuitive sense.

Here's the solution for reference

[image]

**Conceptual Confusion**
The main concept I am struggling with is the instantaneous centere of rotation of the disc.I tried reading up about it on wikipedia but that doesn't clarify it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observer on the plank sees the rotating disc move away in the y-direction at an increasing velocity in that direction.

So what is observed is the sum of the rotation of the disc about its centre and a translation in the y-direction of the centre of the disc.

This is shown below at times $t=0,\,t,\,t'$.

[image]

Relative to the centre of the disc the speed of the rim of the disc is $V$ and at the given intervals of time the velocity of the centre of the disc is $v=0,\,v,\,v'$.
The instantaneous centre of rotation is $R$.